# Tensorflow - show the gradients on all the neurons (not just the input variables)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am implementing a neural network using the Adam optimizer which utilizes gradients. Here is a brief look on my code

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

And this is how I feed in the data:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
# Initialize variables
sess.run(init)

# Training cycle
for epoch in range(150):
    avg_cost = 0.
    total_batch = int(X_train.shape[0]/batch_size)
    batch_range = list(range(batch_size, int(X_train.shape[0]),batch_size))
    # Loop over all batches
    i = 0
    while i < total_batch - 1:
        start_idx = batch_range[i]
        end_idx = batch_range[i+1]
        batch_x, batch_y = X_train.iloc[start_idx:end_idx,:], y_train.iloc[start_idx:end_idx,:]
        # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                      y: batch_y})
        # Compute average loss
        avg_cost += c / total_batch
        i = i + 1
```

However, I would like to show gradients on all the neurons in the hidden layers (i.e. all the gradients used in the backprop). I tried to look up the relevant function, but all the functions that I found only compute the gradients with respect to the input variables. Can I please get a hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, the optimizer does compute and apply gradients to all the layers in your network. If you want to have direct access to gradients before they are applied, you can split up your training op as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/optimizers#processing_gradients_before_applying_them)

Comment: @MadWombat That's actually what I looked at. What I should put in as <list of variables>? In essence, the list should be the list of neurons but I'm not sure how that should work in Tensorflow.

Comment: The list of variables is usually all your trainable variables, weights and biases. I think TF automatically maintains the list for you in tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the builtin debugger of TensorFlow called `tfdbg` (available in versions 0.12+). It exposes all the intermediate Tensors (along with graph structure) during `Session.run()` calls.

See a walk-through at: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/debugger/

The basic workflow is as follows. First you wrap your Session object right before the training Session.run() is called.

```
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
```

Then when the sess.run() occurs, you will drop to the `tfdbg>` command line interface. Issue the `tfdbg> run` command and you will then see a list of all intermediate Tensors generated during the `sess.run()` call, including the gradients.

If you want to access the gradients programmatically, instead of interactively, `tfdbg` has a Python API available as well. See:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf_debug/

Comment: wish I could like an answer more than once